# Background Image not showing in PDF using WKHTMLTOPDF

Tags: javascript, php, pdf-generation, background-image, wkhtmltopdf

**Scenario :**

> I'm generating the Report in pdf format using WKHTMLTOPDF tool, Every
>   thing works fine except the background image is not rendering in
>   generated PDF.While it is showing properly in HTML format.

**What i have tried :**

> - I have changed the format of background image from png to jpg but no    Luck.
> - I have used the `--javascript-delay 5000` code in WKHTMLTOPDF,    for waiting to render the image but still no luck.

**Strange Behavior :**

> I have one more different image with background and it is showing
>   properly.

**My Question :**

> What is wrong with this scnerio, As the other image is showing
>   properly with background but not this one ? Please help me .Thanks.

**Updated :**

> I'm executing the cmd
>
> ```
> My Code: wkhtmltopdf http://example.com/renderpdf sample.pdf
> ```
>
> And while executing getting the warnings :
>
> ```
> QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
> ```

**Used CSS :**

> ```
> background: transparent url(images/abc.png) no-repeat scroll 0% 0% / 100% 100%;
> ```

Comment: Just in case, you are sure the path to the background is correct?

Comment: @entiendoNull , yes I'm pretty much sure that image path is correct and it is rendering properly on HTML.

Comment: Try adding the complete path to where the image file is located instead of a relative one and see if that helps...

Comment: @Downvoters , Please explain the reason.

Comment: @entiendoNull I'm giving the exact relative path like `http://example.com/assets/images.abc.png`

Comment: Are you using bootstrap per chance? Also if you are using --print-media check what it looks like when doing print via the browser.

Comment: @DMH No I'm not using Bootstrap. I have tried using `--print-media-type` but still no luck.

Comment: On your comment above you are using the path `http://example.com/assets/images.abc.png` isnt that meant to be `http://example.com/assets/images/abc.png`

Comment: ahh yest that was mistake in my comment, but it was proper in code.

Comment: Show some code then? :)

Comment: @entiendoNull, Updated accordingly.

Comment: Do you see any messages saying it cannot load the image file? When ever I create a pdf I do see it will say cannot load 'image' 404 or something along those lines. Also what version are you using? Have you tried another version?

Comment: @DMH  No there is no such message regarding Image not found. I'm using the `0.12.1 (with patched qt)` and i was facing the issues with old version thats why i'm using latest version.

Comment: weird. Is the web page you want to make a pdf available for us to see?

Comment: @DMH Sorry due to some security policy I can't show you that.

Comment: Fair enough. Can you paste the css that sets the background?

Comment: @DMH see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks I just looked. Does the background load if the url for the website does not end with a `/`. I have had issues with this in the past. Also with the css try adding `url(/images/abc.png)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89683/discussion-between-harshal-mahajan-and-dmh).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wicked PDF +fonts+heroku+rails3.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734375/wicked-pdf-fontsherokurails3-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out; the problem was with my CSS.

I changed it from:

```
background: transparent url(http://example.com/abc.png) no-repeat scroll 0% 0% / 100% 100%;
```

to:

```
background:url(http://example.com/abc.png) no-repeat; background-size:100%` 100%;
```

Comment: what was the issue with this exactly? not having a background-size specified? or that you previously had a syntax error? I still cannot get my image to display :(

Answer (score 1):

Does your image file name contain whitespaces? If yes, use [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) function on your file name (not your complete file path) and try.

Comment: No My file name doesn't contains the white-spaces.